# angularjs already selected value should not apprear in another multiple dropdowns from json

Tags: angularjs, json, jsp

I need your help.
I'm implementing multiple dropdowns using ng-repeat from json. And I want that once value is selected in one dropdown it should not appear in another dropdowns. i'm new in angularjs. here is my json. I want "data" in drop down with selected value columnindex.

```
$scope.records = [
    {
        "userId": "10",
        "fisrtname": "Unnati",
        "lastName": "Chauhan",
        "dateVal": "22-05-2016",
        "columnindex": "1",
        "data": [{value: 1, text: 'USERID'},
            {value: 2, text: 'FIRSTNAME'},
            {value: 3, text: 'LASTNAME'},
            {value: 4, text: 'DOB'}]
    },
    {
        "userId": "20",
        "fisrtname": "Ranju",
        "lastName": "Shinde",
        "dateVal": "21-05-2016",
        "columnindex": "2",
        "data": [{value: 1, text: 'USERID'},
            {value: 2, text: 'FIRSTNAME'},
            {value: 3, text: 'LASTNAME'},
            {value: 4, text: 'DOB'}]
    },
    {
        "userId": "30",
        "fisrtname": "Smruti",
        "lastName": "Modi",
        "dateVal": "20-05-2016",
        "columnindex": "3",
        "data": [{value: 1, text: 'USERID'},
            {value: 2, text: 'FIRSTNAME'},
            {value: 3, text: 'LASTNAME'},
            {value: 4, text: 'DOB'}]
    }];
```

my html code is

```
 <div ng-controller="multipleDropDown">
        <div ng-repeat= "us in records" >

            <select ng-model="us.columnindex" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in us.data|arrayDiff:us.data:item.value">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please help me. I really need solution

Comment: Can you please share your html code??

Comment: <div ng-controller="multipleDropDown">
            <div ng-repeat= "us in records" >

                <select ng-model="us.columnindex" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in us.data|arrayDiff:us.data:item.value">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: hello ruhul this is my html code

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem. Do you want to set the data dropdown to the `coulumindex` at first load? Something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0zaov93t/)?

Comment: You can use lodash utility (_.filter) to exclude selected item from first dropdown to show in the second dropdown list. 
Use of Angular multiselect will make it easy for you to deal with dropdowns. Link :  isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/

Comment: I want that if value is already selected in one dropdown it should not appear in another drop downs.

Comment: @  AWolf sir---------------------

thank you for fiddle...
but if user select userid then it shold not appear in another drop down..

this is I acually want sir,,, plz plz plz help me

Answer (score -1):

you need to add below code in your dropdown elements so as to avoid recursive calls to all three of your dropdowns during change in `ng-model` values.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change', debounce: { change: 0 } }"
```

Also there is a function which updates `data` object of your `$scope.records` array. Please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zaov93t/38/). I think this is what the specific thing is which you wanted.