# selected value in one dropdown should not appear in another dropdowns. how to remove selected element?

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, jsp

Sorry for asking this question again. but I'm new to angularjs. my que is...
I have five drop downs which are loading from json using angular js(ng-option). now I need that if user selecting value in one drop down that same value should not appear in another four dropdowns.

I really want solution. I search a lot and practice more and more but. Couldn't find any solution. Plz plz plz help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs already selected value should not apprear in another multiple dropdowns from json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367411/angularjs-already-selected-value-should-not-apprear-in-another-multiple-dropdown)

Comment: no sir, there is no any solution which I want

Comment: What are your criteria for a solution and why don't they apply to the duplicate suggested?

Comment: Have you seen the  answer I have posted below ? Do let me know if that was what your were looking for to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've got your problem right, but I would try to create an array, let's say $scope.selectedOptions. And then on select push the value to this array. After that you can filter the options in other dropdowns with lodash for example.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that you can apply in easy way.
one model you sending to other select.

```
<select  ng-model="countryList"
 data-ng-options="countryList for countryList in countryListArray" ng-change="getStates(countryList)" >
<option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose Country--</option>
```

```
 <select  ng-disabled="!countryList"  ng-model="stateList"
     data-ng-options="stateList for stateList in stateListArray" ng-change="getCities(stateList)" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose State --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below code in your dropdown elements so as to avoid recursive calls to all three of your dropdowns during change in `ng-model` values.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change', debounce: { change: 0 } }"
```

Also there is a function which updates `data` object of your `$scope.records` array. Please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zaov93t/38/). I think this is what the specific thing is which you wanted.